# Get next from array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

i am so stuck , please someone help if you have 2 min.

i have a foreach where I get values from session something like

```
foreach ($result as $i => $item ) {

         $values_array  = explode("\n",$get_widths); // outputs Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 180) 
         // here I need to echo the value from the array but only ONCE
}
```

the issue is that this is used by 2 or more items and array outputs gets repeated every time , so if 2 items i get 
Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 180) Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 180)  or 
120 120 
instead

120 180

for actual code see here

```
<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item){
    $i=0;
    $is_group                   = $item_params->get('is_group');    
    $group_widths               = $item_params->get('group_widths');    
    $group_widths_array         = explode("\n",$group_widths);

    if($is_group == 1){

        echo $group_widths_array[$i];
    }



}
?>
```

please note I cant move outside the foreach. thank you

Comment: I think you will need to get rid of the foreach, and use `for`

Comment: I cant do it , have to use foreach

Comment: Why? Is this homework, or a test of discipline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am completely missing the point of this loop...

You are iterating over an array, assigning the key to `$i` and the value to `$item` but then you set `$i` to 0, echoing `$group_widths_array[0]` every time your condition is met and `$item` you don´t use at all...

That can´t be right, can it?

Anyway, it seems to me that the reason that your output is repeated is that you output `$group_widths_array[0]` every time and `$is_group` is the same on every iteration.

Comment: you right , i am at 0 all the time which is first value , what should I set the $ at than ?

Comment: @Benn Nothing at all, it is set in the `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a flag variable of some sort to determine if we have processed yet or not.

```
$values_array  = explode("\n",$get_widths);
if (!isset($we_have_outputted)) {
   echo '<pre>'. print_r($values_array, true) .'</pre>';
   $we_have_outputted = true;
}
```

Comment: this was close , but I am getting the first value only , only 120 , I need the full array once